# When is passing a pointer to another thread in C++11 a race condition?

Tags: c++, c++11, race-condition

does this code have a race condition?

```
auto x = make_shared<Fun>(1984); //could also be raw ptr
auto t = thread(func, x);
```

Also Herb Sutter in his talk at C++ and Beyond used a concurrent queue.

So if I have a queue `q`,

```
auto x  = new Fun(1984);
q.push(x);

//other thread 
auto ptr = q.pop();
```

Is this a race condition? Is it possible for the other thread to pop `ptr` and still see the stale values of the memory location where `ptr` points to?  Since concurrent queue is not in the standard, lets presume I'm using the PPL/TBB one.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. There is no race condition in the first example, because the thread constructor causes sequential consistency. The second example depends on the implementation of the _queue_. Can you try to make the question clearer?

Comment: *Passing* a pointer is never a problem. What you do with it inside could be.

Comment: @nosid like I said in the second example to me question is will other thread see *ptr content correctly aka what the ptr points to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No in both cases.

The first example would *in principle* be a definite race condition if it wasn't for some special properties of `std::thread`.
The compiler is in principle allowed to reorder moves, however constructing a thread object has sequential consistency, which formally guarantees that it works. But even if it didn't have that property, creating and starting a thread in practice takes a very considerable time (hundred thousands to millions of times as long as executing a few move instructions) so you would practically (not formally, but practically) be guaranteed that there is no race, even if there was no sequential consistency (this "practical guarantee" is admittedly somewhat disputable, it might not hold true in contrieved extreme cases, but the formal guarantee is true either way).

The second example uses a concurrent queue, which by definition is engineered (either using a lock or using a lockfree algorithm) in such a manner that no race condition occurs.<sup>1</sup>

In either case, the pointer that ends up being in the queue is guaranteed to be either not there at all (in which case the `pop` operation will block or fail, where "fail" means that the consuming thread knows that there is no valid pointer available at this time -- it will not assume some invalid value) or it is there in a valid state.
The atomic (locked or lock-free) operation that adds the pointer to the queue guarantees that the object construction which happened before is also realized before (i.e. no pointer on queue without valid object).
This implies that the object must also be valid when its pointer is retrieved from the queue (unless you cheat).

---

<sup>1</sup>This obviously assumes correct operation of the queue, but that's a fair assumption.

Comment: I know about the ptr being there or not, problem is the *ptr aka the thing it points to... Is it guaranteed that other thread will see that content correctly

Comment: The object is constructed before the pointer is intered into the concurrent queue, which either goes through an atomic operation or a lock. This is a happens-after guarantee within the same thread either way (not across threads, but within the producer), so unless you cheat and overwrite the object with some garbage after pushing the pointer, there's no way the other thread could retrieve a pointer that does _not_ point to a valid object. The consumer might of course not be able to retrieve a pointer immediately (and might have to spin or block), but whatever it retrieves is necessarily valid.

Answer (score 0):

There *might* be race conditions, but only if the pointer `x` is used when the other thread gets around to using its copy of it.

A function like this:

```
void CreateWork(Queue& q){
    auto x  = new Fun(1984);
    // could use x here
    q.push(x);
}
```

should have no race conditions because once `x` is in the queue the thread that calls `CreateWork` has no access to `x`.